# Only first request works in bouncy

Tags: node.js

We are using a node.js script based on bouncy to manage a lot of small tools we run.
It proxies the traffic to a certain ip:port depending on the incomming hostname.

We deceided to add the ip address of the original reqquest as an 'x-forwarded-for' header and ran into a problem. The header is only included in the first request and not on any subsequent ones. On further inspection we noticed the coude isn't even being executed again.

I have made the following demo to show my problem:

```
var bouncy = require('bouncy');

var server = bouncy(function (req, res, bounce) {
    console.log("test");
    bounce ("echo.200please.com", {headers: {'x-forwarded-for': req.connection.remoteAddress}});
});

server.listen(9000);
```

"test" is only written to the console on the first request. I assume there is some caching going on in bouncy but if so i feel the custom header should be included the second time aswell.

Does anybody know what is going on here and if this is a bug or somehow a feature?

Answer (score 0):

**That is a feature.**

**If you want to make a log for filter, you can capture request like this:**

```
server.on('request', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
})

server.listen(9000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a feature or bug, but what I'm doing is to store the IP address on the application level. For example in nodejs I'm doing this:

```
  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
           req.socket.ip ||
           req.connection.remoteAddress ||                
           req.socket.remoteAddress ||
           req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;

  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-for']) {
       req.socket.ip = ip;
  }
```

Now I have in req.socket.ip the ip address. Not sure if this is best solution, but it works.